# Basis and points in $C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I had two points and some variable $x$.

Would the points $(x, 0)$ and $(0, 6x)$ be linearly independent?

I ask this because clearly you cannot get one from the other, but does the presence of $x$ in both points  matter?

Comment: Are you saying $x\ne0$?

Comment: Are you in a vector space of pairs of functions?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say $C^2$ @HennoBrandsma

Comment: and no $x$ can be $0$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent iff the only solution to the equation
$$\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2=0$$
is $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$.

Let's plug your vectors to this equation:

$$\alpha_1(x, 0) + \alpha_2(0, 6x) = x(\alpha_1, 6\alpha_2) = 0$$
Hence if $x\neq 0$ we have $(\alpha_1, 6\alpha_2)=0$ and $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ meaning that these vectors are linearly independent.
However if $x=0$, we can have $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ (or whatever), meaning that these vectors are *not* linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

You're in $\Bbb R^2$, so a variable $x$ must have a concrete value, and for every concrete $x\neq 0$ these vectors will be independent, yes. Or are you working in a vector space of pairs of functions?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say $C^2$

Comment: You mean $\Bbb C^2$? Then $x$ still needs to have a value, and $\neq 0$ too. Then the same holds.